# AWS javascript sdk v3 not working with EC2 credentials via IAM roles

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

```
   const config = {
      region: process.env.AWS_REGION,
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
        secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
      };,
    };
```

I have updated my AWS SDK from v2 to v3 and my AWS EC2 already have IAM role for accessing S3 bucket. When I try to run the code in the same machine I am getting error regarding credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please double-check your IAM role permission, if all is good following should work.

```
const AWS = require('@aws-sdk/client-s3');

async function init() {
        const params = { Bucket: 'bucket_name', Key: 'test.json' };
        const s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: 'ap-southeast-2', signatureVersion: 'v4' });
        const response = await s3.getObject(params);
        const fileContent = await response.Body.transformToString();
}

init();
```

Read the following doc fromEnv() if you are providing credentials via env.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/functions/_aws_sdk_credential_providers.fromEnv.html